# Logback configuration: factoring out reusable parts

Tags: logback

Is there a way to factor out and parameterize repeating parts of Logback XML configuration? I have many different rolling file appenders configured basically the same except for the file names. I use that in conjunction with a bunch of loggers with their 'additivity' turned off so I can redirect different parts of the stack to different files. This adds up to a cumbersome and long configuration file composed of many almost identical segments.

I've used Logback's `<include>` feature before, but it doesn't address this reuse issue since I can't parameterize the included configuration. I'd expect such a feature to look something akin to:

```
<include resource="file-appender.xml">
    <property name="filePath" value="/where/logs/go" />
    <property name="baseLogger" value="com.mycompany.thatpartofthestack" />
</include>
```

But as far as I understand that's wishful thinking. Is there another way of factoring out Logback's configuration via templates, macros, functions or whatnot?

Comment: I've created an issue to add support of this in Logback: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1104

Answer (score 2):

Try using [variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) in local and/or context [scope](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes).

Perhaps the easiest way is to define variables in some resource file, say `logback.properties` bundled with each each application. Moreover, each application would carry a `logback.xml` file importing `logback.properties`.

```
<configuration debug="true">
  <property resource="logback.properties" />
  <!-- set root level as given by the value of the root.level variable -->
  <!-- if root.level is undefined default to DEBUG -->
  <root level="${root.level:-DEBUG}"/>
</configuration>
```

If you wish to set the root level to WARN in webapp-A, simply add the following line in `logback.properties` file bundled with webapp-A.

```
root.level=WARN
```

You can bundle `logback.xml` as a resource in a artifact common to your various applications.

Comment: I'd like the logging configuration file(s) to reside in a configuration directory outside the bundled application. I programmatically load the configuration for that purpose. Does this mechanism depend on automatic configuration files discovery or can I just call `configurator.setContext(context)` several times consequtively without calling `reset` and thus loading multiple configuration files? Unless I'm missing something here, I still can't see a way to parameterize the configuration file loaded from outside the file. I guess I could always template it and generate configurations on the fly.

Comment: It's even easier if you are invoking joran programmatically. Just try it.

Comment: how to use it in logback.groovy?